# Dynamically change Google Chart Gauge data and colors based on cell value

Tags: javascript, charts, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-gauges

I'm making a dashboard in Google Spreadsheet and would like to use cell data. Now you need to hard code the data and the values for redFrom, redTo etc etc but I want them to be dynamic and dependant on a certain value in a cell. Same applies to the values shown by the gauge.

The dashboard will to track monthly income and the gauge will indicate if someone if in the green for that month based on the percentage relative to their target.

This is the standard example from google:

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['Memory', 80],
          ['CPU', 55],
          ['Network', 68]
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 400, height: 120,
          redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
          yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(0, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 13000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(1, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 5000);
        setInterval(function() {
          data.setValue(2, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 26000);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 400px; height: 120px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I want it to be something like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gauge']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['A1', A2],
          ['B1', B2],
          ['C1', C2]
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: 400, height: 120,
          redFrom: D1, redTo: D2,
          yellowFrom:D3, yellowTo: D4,
          minorTicks: 5
        };
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: for clarification, are you building the dashboard in the spreadsheet? or building the dashboard on a web page, and want to pull values from the spreadsheet?

Comment: @WhiteHat I planned on making a dashboard menu calling html pages within the spreadsheet liek so `function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Dashboard')
      .addItem('Open1', 'openDialog')
      .addToUi();
}
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(1000)
      .setHeight(750);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, 'My custom dialog');
}`

Answer (score 0):

if the charts will be running in an html page,
you can query the sheet using --> `google.visualization.Query`

following is an example, using a sample spreadsheet --> [gauge data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16IeSOMvl4-B3qFr386kjZA-vSRIHTNvSIigqyracGj0/edit#gid=0)

columns A & B are used for the gauge chart data

columns D-I are for the from / to color values

the `setQuery` method is used to separate the two ranges into data tables

first, get the chart data, the options data, then draw the chart...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['gauge']
}).then(function () {

  // get chart data
  var queryChart = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16IeSOMvl4-B3qFr386kjZA-vSRIHTNvSIigqyracGj0/edit#gid=0');
  queryChart.setQuery('select A,B');
  queryChart.send(function (responseChart) {

    var dataChart = responseChart.getDataTable();

    // get options data
    var queryOptions = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16IeSOMvl4-B3qFr386kjZA-vSRIHTNvSIigqyracGj0/edit#gid=0');
    queryOptions.setQuery('select D,E,F,G,H,I');
    queryOptions.send(function (responseOptions) {

      var dataOptions = responseOptions.getDataTable();

      var options = {
        minorTicks: 5
      };

      options.redFrom = dataOptions.getValue(0, 0);
      options.redTo = dataOptions.getValue(0, 1);
      options.yellowFrom = dataOptions.getValue(0, 2);
      options.yellowTo = dataOptions.getValue(0, 3);
      options.greenFrom = dataOptions.getValue(0, 4);
      options.greenTo = dataOptions.getValue(0, 5);

      var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'))
      chart.draw(dataChart, options);
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm having some problems running this in a html page. Any chance you can help me out with that as well? Within Google Spreadsheet I'm using the function openDialog with and then call a html page within the dialog, but I'm not succesful in loading this code into a html page.

Comment: never used code within a google spreadsheet, but i can try to help -- when you load the html, is it from a file already saved somewhere?